# adding title to a flowchart in R

Tags: r, flowchart

I am havingbelow lines

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("                          
digraph {    
     graph [layout = dot,
     rankdir = TB,
     overlap = true,
     fontsize = 10,
     title='title']
```

All parameters are okay except the title does not show, wondering how should I go about it? Many thanks.

Comment: You need to share a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this as `label` instead of `title`, see if it works for you:

```
 library(DiagrammeR)
 chart<- graph [layout = dot,
     rankdir = TB,
     overlap = true,
     fontsize = 10,
     label='title']
```

EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:

I believe adding the render statement to the object will get you there, but you may need to tweak how you create the object `chart`

```
chart%>% render_graph(title = "Title")
```

Comment: thanks I tried this one but the title falls at the bottom of the chart, any method I can locate the title at the top of chart ? Thanks.